# iOS Core Data "optimistic locking failure"

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I've got a really frustrating problem that I'd like help understanding and perhaps even fixing.

I'm learning Core Data by building a rather simple app.

My model is as follows:

**User**

*Attributes*

- name
- gender
- dob

*Relationships*

- hasCompletedItem - "A user can complete many list items, A list item can be completed by many users"
- isInAgeGroup - "A user is in one AgeGroup, an AgeGroup can contain multiple users"

**AgeGroup**

*Attributes*

- title

*Relationships*

- hasItems - "An AgeGroup has many ListItems associated with it, a ListItem can only be associated with one AgeGroup"
- hasUsers - "An AgeGroup has many users associated with it, A user can only be in 1 AgeGroup"

**ListItem**

*Attributes*

- itemText

*Relationships*

- completedByUser - "A list item can be completed by many users, a user can complete many list items".
- forAgeGroup - "A list item is assigned to a single AgeGroup, an AgeGroup can have multiple listItems"

My program is set up as follows:

- The AppDelegate handles creating the CoreData stack.
- didFinishLaunchingWithOptions accesses MenuViewController and passes through the managedObjectContext for it to use:

```c
id navigationController = [[self window] rootViewController];
id controller = [navigationController topViewController];
[controller setManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

- The MenuViewController displays. It is a UIViewController with a few buttons which each segue to other view controllers.
- When the 'Start' button is pressed on the MenuViewController, the existing managedObjectContext is passed on in the prepareForSegue method:

```c
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"selectprofile"]) {
        [[segue destinationViewController] setManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    }
}
```

- The SelectProfileTableViewController is then shown. It lists each User in a table. It has a button to allow adding new Users. The data for the tableview is provided by an NSFetchedResultsController which basically just fetches all records from the User entity.
- Tapping the "Add" button will load the AddProfileViewController but not before passing on the managedObjectContext:

```c
AddProfileViewController *viewController = (AddProfileViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
[viewController setManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

- The AddProfileViewController is just a UIViewController. It has textFields for the name, D.O.B, etc.
- It has a method addProfileDone that gets called when the user taps the "Done" button. In this method a new User managedObject is created and its attributes are set:

```c
User *newMO = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

newMO.name = self.nameTextField.text;
newMO.dob = _dob;
// etc
```

- Next, it also attempts to set the relationship between this new User entity and it's corresponding AgeGroup entity.

```c
NSFetchRequest *ageGroupRecordRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AgeGroup"];

NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"title"
                                                      ascending:YES];
[ageGroupRecordRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

// Make a predicate to find the correct AgeGroup based on what was calculated
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(title == %@)", ageGroup];
[ageGroupRecordRequest setPredicate:predicate];

// Run the fetch request, should only ever get 1 result back.
NSError *fetchError;

// Result will be an array with a single AgeGroup entity
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:ageGroupRecordRequest error:&fetchError];


// Set up the relationship using the fetched entity
// Crashes when saving if below line is uncommented
newMO.isInAgeGroup = fetchedObjects[0];
```

- As noted in the code, when the line is uncommented and the managedObjectContext goes to save, i get the following error:

  CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure: optimistic locking failure with (null)
  CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Old save request was:  { inserts ((
      "0x942dd40 "
  )), updates ((
      "0x8e4ed60 "
  )), deletes () locks () }
  2014-04-12 20:00:09.482 ChekList[6076:60b] CoreData: error: failed to resolve optimistic locking failure.  Next attempt will be:  { inserts ((
      "0x942dd40 "
  )), updates ((
      "0x8e4ed60 "
  )), deletes () locks () }
  sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
  annotation: getting max pk for entityID = 3
  annotation: updating max pk for entityID = 3 with old = 4017 and new = 4018
  sql: COMMIT
  sql: BEGIN EXCLUSIVE
  sql: UPDATE ZAGEGROUP SET Z_OPT = ?  WHERE Z_PK = ? AND (Z_OPT = ? OR Z_OPT IS NULL)
  details: SQLite bind[0] = (int64)1
  details: SQLite bind[1] = (int64)6
  details: SQLite bind[2] = nil
  sql: ROLLBACK
  sql: SELECT Z_PK,Z_OPT FROM ZAGEGROUP WHERE Z_PK IN (6) ORDER BY Z_PK
  annotation: sql execution time: 0.0006s

My understanding is that basically something else has modified the context, and during the save CoreData has noticed this and stopped. I've read about changing the MergePolicy on the ManagedObjectContext but I don't really want to do this without knowing why I have to.

It's interesting to note that if I comment out the line that attempts to set the relationship it works fine. (except of course the relationship isn't set)

As far as I can see I am passing the managedObjectContext correctly to each view controller. I have also made sure that there are not multiple contexts accessing the same persistent store.

Is it likely to be the FetchedResultsController in the previous View Controller that is modifying the context for some reason?

Is anyone able to offer some information and perhaps a possible solution? I'd rather not have to change the merge policy. I can't see why I should have to considering its a rather simple example. I've been pulling my hair out most of the day on this.

I can't help but think it's most likely something simple I'm missing.

Thanks,
Brett.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the solution.

Turns out that my whole problem was caused by my preloaded database. 
I have a preloaded database that I copy over in the AppDelegate. Turns out that something was wrong with it.

I found this out by commenting out the lines that copied the database over and instead manually added the preloaded data in the AppDelegate. I was able to add data and also set the relationships.

From there I created a new preloaded database and it works fine.

I also found a great Apple developer example -

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html

Which also showed me an alternative way of adding new entities. In this case they create the actual entity in the prepareForSegue method and pass just the entity not the entire context.

I changed my app to use that method as well (before I figured out that the database was the issue) but it still crashed. I've decided to keep it that way though as it seems more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but the suggested solution wasn't working for me. What worked was to create the context using concurrency type: `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` even though I don't need it and I'm not using concurrency at all but somehow copying the preloaded database created the optimistic locking failure. Then wrap the save call in a the context's `performBlockAndWait:`

To create the context:

```
[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
```

To save changes:

```
__block NSError *error = nil;
__block BOOL savedOK = NO;
[managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
   savedOK = [managedObjectContext save:&error];
}];
```

This is even documented in iOS API, look for [Concurrency](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/) inside  `NSManagedObjectContext` class.

Comment: Found out this wasn't a solution. The issue was that my reflexive relationship needed to be saved before adding objects to the other non-reflexive relationships of that table.